# How does one get a command to execute on startup on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, startup, execute-command

I would like a command to execute when my PC starts up.
My OS is Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.
The command is:

```
xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync && xrandr --addmode VGA-1 1920x1080_60.00 && xrandr --output VGA-1 --mode 1920x1080_60.00
```

It works perfectly when I execute it (from the Terminal) after the pc has booted up. I have tried various options (after internet searches) but can't get any of them to work - have tried both command line and GUI profferings - none has worked.

Comment: xrandr commands affect the X server, The X server starts **after** you login, so using all the boot tools (cron @reboot, systemd services, runlevel 3, etc) that run before login won't work. Try putting it into a script and placing the script in  ~.config/autostart, which runs each time you login after X server is up and running.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run scripts on start up?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/814/how-to-run-scripts-on-start-up) See this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/500147/480481

Comment: Xrandr, and usually keyboard- related commands need a little break https://github.com/algent-al/solus-extra-repo/tree/master/packages

Comment: Thanks - I have tried some of these but get lost - they assume knowledge I don't have (70-year-old noob).  I will try all of them then come back here.  I do appreciate your help and don't wan't to be a nuisance.

Comment: This looks like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). You don't necessarily want to run `xrandr` anything, you actually want your screen resolution to be something other than what it is when you start up. You should instead look into why the resolution is different in the first place, as that will lead to a proper solution.

Comment: Many thanks, this did the trick!  I used the Startup application and the following codeline: /bin/bash -c "sleep 15 && cvt 1920 1080 && xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync && xrandr --addmode VGA-1 1920x1080_60.00 && xrandr --output VGA-1 --mode 1920x1080_60.00" - So very grateful for your help - you people are MAGNIFICENT!  Thanks so much.

Comment: To Michael Hampton: I did look into why the optimal screen resolution was not being implemented (it was working for a number of YEARS!).  The optimal screen resolution was not offered when I went to select it under settings - looks like a bug has been introduced into my Ubuntu 18.04.  That is why I took this route.  Thanks for your time anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You could try putting the command in `/etc/rc.local`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, I am a 70-year-old noob and not sure how to do this. Could you elaborate? I would be most grateful. (If I should be posting this elsewhere, do please let me know - I don't want to irritate anyone).